# 'stateInfo.state' filter not working for GCP IAM Recommender API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-recommendation

I'm trying to query the GCP IAM recommender API (API documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/review-apply-role-recommendations#review-apply)) and fetch role revision recommendations for my project. I'm looking for ACTIVE recommendations only. However, the input filter `stateInfo.state` filter (listed in the above documentation) is not working for me. It returns the error `Invalid Filter`. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Here's my API query: https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-demo-project/locations/global/recommenders/google.iam.policy.Recommender/recommendations?filter=stateInfo.state:ACTIVE

Comment: `stateInfo.state=ACTIVE`? See [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.recommenders.recommendations/list#query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Please include a minimally reproducible example in questions:

```bash
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]
LOCATION="global"

SERVICES=(
  "cloudresourcemanager"
  "recommender"
)
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES[@]}
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

ACCOUNT="tester"
EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Minimal role for Recommender for IAM
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/recommender.iamViewer

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Be careful this overwrites the default gcloud auth account
# Remember to revert this to your e.g. me@gmail.com afterwards
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json


TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token ${EMAIL})
RECOMMENDER="google.iam.policy.Recommender"
PARENT="projects/${PROJECT}/locations/${LOCATION}/recommenders/${RECOMMENDER}"
FILTER="stateInfo.state=ACTIVE"

curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/${PARENT}/recommendations?filter=${FILTER}
```

Yields (HTTP 200):

```
{}
```

Comment: Hey Daz, the entire script wasn't necessary. But the line where you apply the `stateInfo.state` filter helped. I understood where I went wrong. It's supposed to be `filter=stateInfo.state=ACTIVE` (and not `filter=stateInfo.state:ACTIVE` which is what's mentioned in the API documentation). Perhaps, Google should rectify this mistake in their doc. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Btw, would you be able to tell me the difference between an ACTIVE vs. DISMISSED vs. FAILED recommendation? One might say that it's pretty much self-explanatory. But I just want to be sure. It's not mentioned in their doc.

Comment: Have a look at [State](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/key-concepts#state). It summarizes the different states. I'd not used this API before reading your question.

Comment: The intent in providing a comprehensive answer is that others may benefit from finding the question.